# calling classes in /lib from controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

hi i am a bit stuck with this. what i am going to work out is that i have a file called ticket_pdf.rb in lib/ directory which i am planning to generate some invoice PDFs for my app. I want to call a function of this class to generate  the PDFs from my controller actions.

the ticket_pdf.rb looks like this

```
class TicketPDF
  def generate_pdf (purchase)
    puts "Ticket ID = #{purchase.ID}"
  end
end
```

in a controller I action i do this.

```
class Customer::MyController < ApplicationController
  require 'ticket_pdf'

  def show
    ticket = TicketPDF.new
  end
end
```

when i try to create an object like this it give me a 500 error like this one.

```
uninitialized constant Customer::MyController::TicketPDF
```

what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
ticket = ::TicketPDF.new
```

You have created TicketPDF in the top level namespace.